# SQL - How do I sort count(user_id) the count?

Tags: sql, database, sql-order-by

I am attempting to sort find the cohorts of users that have joined events X many times since a date. And output the results with SQL all at once, with them `ORDER`(ed) `BY` the number of events they have joined.

Currently I have the below, and with this I can get the user_id(s) that have appeared once (or twice etc. depending on the `HAVING` value). I'd like to work a way that I can have it displayed in columns, with Col 1 being filled with `count = 1`, Col 2 with `count = 2` etc.

```
SELECT user_id
FROM api_participation
WHERE event_id IN (SELECT id
                   FROM api_events
                   WHERE type IS NOT NULL)
AND user_id IN (SELECT id
                FROM auth_user
                WHERE date_joined >= '2018-05-01 00:00:01' AND current_city_id = 8
                )
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING count(user_id) = 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT cnt, COUNT(*) 
FROM (SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM api_participation
      WHERE event_id IN (SELECT id
                         FROM api_events
                         WHERE type IS NOT NULL)
      AND user_id IN (SELECT id
                      FROM auth_user
                      WHERE date_joined >= '2018-05-01 00:00:01' AND current_city_id = 8
                      )
      GROUP BY user_id
     ) u
GROUP BY cnt
ORDER BY cnt;
```

Comment: This has almost worked :), I removed the `GROUP BY user_id)` from the subset. And that then puts out all of the user_id(s), with their count next to them. What I was trying to ask is is it possible for the columns to be cnt(1), cnt(2), cnt(3) etc relevant to the count found from the query?

Comment: @Hamish . . . There was a typo -- or rather, missing expression.  That should be `count(*) as cnt`.

Answer (score 0):

The following may be used :

```
SELECT user_id, count(user_id) as "count"

.......

ORDER BY "count";
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want col1 and col2 you may can handle it like this:

```
select a.user_id as col1,b.user_id as col2 from
(SELECT user_id
FROM api_participation
WHERE event_id IN (SELECT id
                   FROM api_events
                   WHERE type IS NOT NULL)
AND user_id IN (SELECT id
                FROM auth_user
                WHERE date_joined >= '2018-05-01 00:00:01' AND current_city_id = 8
                )
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING count(user_id) = 1) a
full join (SELECT user_id
FROM api_participation
WHERE event_id IN (SELECT id
                   FROM api_events
                   WHERE type IS NOT NULL)
AND user_id IN (SELECT id
                FROM auth_user
                WHERE date_joined >= '2018-05-01 00:00:01' AND current_city_id = 8
                )
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING count(user_id) = 2)b on b.user_id=a.user_id
```